# Clarification about JDBC failover / High Availability with MariaDB

Tags: mysql, jdbc, mariadb, database-replication, high-availability

I have setup a small cluster using two MariaDB 10.2 databases, one is (active) master and the other standby (passive master). I have enabled GTID and semi-synchronous replication. Say that MDB1 is master and MDB2 is standby, therefore MDB2 replicates MDB1 binlog and MDB1 replicates MDB2 binlog. Of course I write only on MDB1 to avoid conflicts.

My concern is about JDBC parameter: I cannot really understand the difference between **failover**, **replication** and **sequence**.

```
jdbc:mariadb:replication://localhost:3306,localhost:3307/mydb
```

Using **replication** as above it seems to write always on MDB1 (:3306) and to read both from MDB1 and MDB2, right?

In the case I want to write and read always to from MDB1, unless it becomes unavailable, which is the correct setup?

And how can I avoid inconsistencies when MDB1 became available again? Is this guaranteed by the usage of GTID?

I have followed those guides:

- [Availability with MariaDB TX: The Definitive Guide p11](http://go.mariadb.com/GLBL-WC2017GuidetoHAwithMariaDB_LP-Registration.html)
- [Failoverand High availability with MariaDB Connector/J](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/failover-and-high-availability-with-mariadb-connector-j/)

Answer (score 0):

What you should use is `sequential`
According to the documentation,

'''
if the failover and load-balancing mode is set to replication, then the connector assumes that the first host is master, and the others are slaves by default, if their types are not explicitly mentioned. 
'''